# Is there any standard JSF converter from inputText to URL?

Tags: java, jsf

I'm trying to convert `inputText` to `java.net.URL` in JSF page:

```
...
<h:form>
  <h:inputText value="${myBean.url}" />
  <h:commandButton type="submit" value="go" />
</h:form>
...
```

My backed bean is:

```
import java.net.URL;
@ManagedBean public class MyBean {
  public URL url;
}
```

Should I implement the converter from scratch or there is some other way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you need to implement a [`Converter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/Converter.html). It's not that hard for this particular case:

```
@FacesConverter(forClass=URL.class)
public class URLConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        }

        try {
            return new URL(value);
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(String.format("Cannot convert %s to URL", value)), e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return "";
        }

        return value.toString();
    }

}
```

Put it somewhere in your project. Thanks to the [`@FacesConverter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/FacesConverter.html) it'll register itself automagically.

Comment: You're welcome. Please note the edit; I was forgotten the `FacesMessage`. It is the one which is to be displayed in a `h:message(s)`.

Comment: You may want to handle null and empty string as well. 
return (value == null || value.isEmpty()) ? null : new URL(value);
and
return value == null ? "" : value.toString();
respectively

Comment: You are amazing! : )

Comment: By the way, I had to add a `if (value == null || value.isEmpty()) return null` because otherwise it complained when a URL field was not filled

Comment: @user1156544: `getAsString()` must return an empty string when value is null. See javadoc. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score -2):

you can implement a Custom Converter

http://www.roseindia.net/jsf/customconverter.shtml

Hope this helps

Comment: That site is however the [worst Java/JSF source](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/06/what-is-it-with-roseindia.html) one can ever recommend to a beginner. Rather suggest another sources.

Comment: Sorry about that O.o i didn't know this
I'm a begginer too and i trying to implement jsf and icefaces and don't find goods code examples, i'll try hard for the next time ;D

Comment: No worries. You are yourself a beginner as well. That site is maintained by amateurs targeting on advertisement incomes only. Almost every code snippet shows/introduces bad practices in one or other way. That customconverter article for example should better have used a `SimpleDateFormat` to convert between Date and String. Also, the fact that JSF has builtin date/time converters is not mentioned at all.

Comment: @BalusC you are so right. I tought JSF to me myself and unfortunately that site pops up quite often if you google for solutions. 90% of the time, i cursed that site for showing me real bullsh**, I can only advise everybody to avoid it.