# What does this checkstyle message means?

Tags: java, checkstyle

This is my code (taken from reply posted at [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415445/is-there-any-standard-jsf-converter-from-inputtext-to-url)):

```
package my;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.convert.ConverterException;
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;
@FacesConverter(forClass = URL.class)
public class UrlConverter implements Converter {
  @Override
  public final Object getAsObject(
    final FacesContext context,
    final UIComponent component,
    final String value) throws ConverterException {
    try {
        return new URL(value);
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        throw new ConverterException(
            String.format("Cannot convert %s to URL", value),
            ex
        );
    }
  }
  @Override
  public final String getAsString(
    final FacesContext context,
    final UIComponent component,
    final Object value) {
    return ((URL)value).toString();
  }
}
```

This is what `maven-checkstyle-plugin` says:

```
UrlConverter.java:0: Got an exception - java.lang.ClassFormatError: 
Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract 
in class file javax/faces/convert/ConverterException
```

What does it mean and how to solve it?

Comment: It looks like checkstyle had a problem parsing the class file for ConverterException. So, while the message says UrlConverter.java, the problem really lies with ConverterException.java

Comment: Looks like that, but what can I do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that checkstyle can't find `javax.faces.convert.ConverterException` class in classpath. Adding this dependency to `pom.xml` solved the problem:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try and exclude the file for being checked:
[How do I suppress all checks for a file in checkstyle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012407/how-do-i-suppress-all-checks-for-a-file-in-checkstyle/)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the javax:javaee-api:6.0 dependency that has the code attribute removed.  You can use org.jboss.spec:jboss-javaee-6.0 as long as you're not using features-maven-plugin from Karaf.